# How can I resolve my BOM's dependencyManagement dependencies?

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-bom

I have a Maven BOM (bill of materials) for a rather large project that contains several hundred dependencies within the `<dependencyManagement>` block. I'd like to verify that all of the dependencies can be successfully resolved before publishing it for the rest of my company.

Unfortunately, the command `mvn dependency:resolve` (as well as the other `dependency` commands like `dependency:tree`) only seems to operate on the standard `<dependencies>` block but ignores `<dependencyManagement>`. Is there some other command I can use to do this?

Comment: This is what I'm looking for long time. currently I'm manually copy the dependency from the dependencyManagement section in a pom.xml and doing `mvn install`

Comment: We have written an enforcer rule that checks the existence of all elements of a BOM (during the build of the BOM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something I also need so I spent couple of hours today to make a plugin that does that. Adding this

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.commsen.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>bom-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>resolve</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>resolve</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

to the BOM's `pom` should make it run during `verify` phase and try to resolve each dependency in the `dependencyManagement` section.

I tested it with a very large BOM and it seems to get the job done.

That said, it is not very well designed nor configurable. There are probably tons of issues (like for example it does not account for qualifiers) to be fixed and improvements to be made.

Give it a try and if you find it useful in general but wish to do something more or better, please [open an issue](https://github.com/commsen/bom-helper-maven-plugin/issues) or better yet, send a [pull request](https://github.com/commsen/bom-helper-maven-plugin) ;)